# Getting maximum and minimum of OpenStreetMap map

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I downloaded for one single city the corresponding openstreetmap data. I want to get the maximum and minimum values for latitude and longitude. How can I do that?

My approach is the following:

```
import osmread as osm
#...
def _parse_map(self):
    geo = [(entity.lat, entity.lon) for entity in osm.parse_file('map.osm') if isinstance(entity, osm.Node)]
    return max(geo[0]), min(geo[0]), max(geo[1]), min(geo[1])
```

But when I print these values I don't think they are right. When I downloaded the area from the OpenStreetMap site I had a white area indicating which region I am exporting. And for this area I also got the minimum and maximum values for latitude and longitude. And these values arent fitting with the ones I get from my simple script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return max(geo[0]), min(geo[0]), max(geo[1]), min(geo[1])
```

You are taking the extrema of the first and second element of `geo`. But `geo` is a list of 2-tuples. So the first element `geo[0]` is a 2-tuple consisting of `entity.lat` and `entity.lon` for the first node. Therefore you are just choosing min/max of latitude and longitude for one node.

If you want to feed the first (second) element of each tuple in the list to the aggregate function, then you have to specifically choose these. For example with a generator:

```
return max(x[0] for x in geo), min(x[0] for x in geo), max(x[1] for x in geo), min(x[1] for x in geo)
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me good results. There might be a few nodes outside the bounding box that I drew on the website, but I think that has to be to display the map correctly within the selected area.